# How to rotate the gradient in the canvas, note: not the canvas itself

Tags: canvas

I have tried rotating the canvas includes transforming and translating, but they didn't work well

[image]

```
  grad = ctx.createRadialGradient(x1,y1,0,x1,y1,Math.pow((x1-x2)**2 + (y1-y2)**2,0.5))    //create radialGradient dynamically
  for (let i = 0; i < gradientList.length; i++) {        //Add colorStop dynamically
    grad.addColorStop(gradientList[i].point / 100, gradientList[i].color)
  }
  ctx.fillStyle = grad;
  ctx.rect(0, 0, w, h)          //draw a rect
  ctx.translate(w/2, h/2);           //and then... I dont know how to rotate
  ctx.rotate(Math.atan2(-x2+x1,y2-y1)/Math.PI);
  ctx.fill()
  ctx.rotate(-Math.atan2(-x2+x1,y2-y1)/Math.PI);
  ctx.translate(-w/2, -h/2);
```

Comment: Any code about what you have achieved?

Comment: Yes, please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example (not a link to an image) of what you're trying to do, and be specific as possible about any issues you have.

Comment: It's quite unclear what you are asking. A radial gradient is circular. Rotating it doesn't mean much. To get the image you shown requires that at some point there have been a scaling applied (best case on your context, worst case by CSS?) . Can you please clarify exactly what you really have and what you want?

Comment: I want to dynamically change the shape of the radial gradient, including changing the long and short radius of the circle, and changing the angle of the gradient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment `I want to dynamically change the shape of the radial gradient` below is an example of how you can do that...

...just a bit of fun with the position of the circles

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

gradientList = ["red","blue","cyan","green"]
circle1 = {x:canvas.width / 2, y:canvas.height / 2, r:10}
circle2 = {x:canvas.width / 2, y:canvas.height / 2, r:100}
i = 0

function draw() {
  i += 0.1
  dx= Math.sin(i)*35
  dy= Math.cos(i)*20
  grad = ctx.createRadialGradient(
    circle1.x - dx, circle1.y - dy, circle1.r, 
    circle2.x + dx, circle2.y + dy, circle2.r + Math.abs(dx)
  ) 
  for (let i = 0; i < gradientList.length; i++) { 
    grad.addColorStop(i / 5, gradientList[i])
  }
  ctx.fillStyle = grad;
  ctx.rect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)    
  ctx.fill()
}

setInterval(draw, 50);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas">
```

But your image looks like an elliptical gradient the `createRadialGradient` creates a radial gradient using the size and coordinates of two circles (there is no long and short radius).
Maybe you want to look at http://fabricjs.com/ they show we can apply gradients to any shapes.

---

I was looking at how they are doing it on **fabricjs** and they are using SVG image...
that is simple enough here is an example

```js
function svgimage() {
  var image = `
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="220" height="200" version="1.1">
      <defs>
        <radialGradient id="grey_blue" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%" fx="20%" fy="40%">
            <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:gray;stop-opacity:0"/>
            <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:blue;stop-opacity:1"/>
        </radialGradient>
      </defs>
      <ellipse cx="110" cy="100" rx="110" ry="100" style="fill:url(#grey_blue)"/>
    </svg>`;
  return encodeURIComponent(image);
}

function drawImage() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width * 2, canvas.height)
  dx = Math.sin(i) * 30
  dy = Math.cos(i) * 20
  ctx.drawImage(img, 50, 0, 200 + dx, 100 + dy);
  i += 0.1
}

function startDrawing() {
  ctx.rotate(20 * Math.PI / 180)
  setInterval(drawImage, 20);
}


var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var i = 0

var img = new Image();
img.onload = startDrawing
img.src = 'data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,' + svgimage();
```

```html
<canvas id=canvas width=250 height=250></canvas>
```

Comment: Wow, so serious answer, thank you very much!
But as you said, what I want is an ellipse. Although your code is great, it is not what I want. I will go to fabricjs to see it, thanks again.

Comment: @Sword I was looking at how they are doing it on fabricjs and they are just using SVG image, I update my answer with a sample

Comment: Sorry, I just saw it. Great solution, let me try it! But I am a little worried about performance issues, whatever, thank you for your rigorous answer! !!